# Mongoose model saves without array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm still trying to get my head out of SQL mode, which may be the reason this is an architectural issue rather than an implementation one but I can't for the life of me figure out how to accomplish the functionality I am trying to attain.

I have a schema, for users. It saves the users to the mongoDB using mongoose without any hassle. It contains generic stuff along the lines of username, password, etc.

However we have a new property to enter into the schema model, this is called achievements and is an array of achievements from another schema. It is declared in the users schema as follows:

```
var UserSchema   = new Schema({
  _id               : { type: String, unique: true },
  group_id          : { type: String, required: true },
  username          : { type: String, required: true },
  achievements      : { type: Array }
});
```

On the UserSchema.save, I am looking up the Achievements model to get an array of achievements that match the same `group_id`, as follows:

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
  var newUser = new User(req.body);

  // Populate the achievements (same group_id)
  Achievement.find()
    .where({ group_id: newUser.group_id })
    .select({ _id: 1 })
    .exec()
    .then(function(achievementsForGroupArray) {

      _.forEach(achievementsForGroupArray, function(achievementForGroup) {
        newUser.achievements.push(achievementForGroup);
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      return res.status(400).send(err).end();
    })

  newUser.save(function(err, user) {
    // .. generic validation stuff ..
  }
```

Now, above, even when replacing the `forEach()` with a straight push of the returned array doesn't work and even replacing the push with simply pushing `'test'` still doesn't populate it.

When I console.log `newUser` before the save, they are in there. When I console.log the `user` part of `newUser.save(function(err, user)` there is no achievements.

**Is my schema setup incorrectly so Mongoose/MongoDB is just dropping it because it doesn't `match` the correct type?**

EDIT: I am certain there are results as when I console log them, I can see them inside the foreach.

Comment: Can you place the "achievementsForGroupArray" object here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stuck in the asynchronous behaviour. Put your newUser.save method inside "then block"(after forEach)

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
  var newUser = new User(req.body);

  // Populate the achievements (same group_id)
  Achievement.find()
    .where({ group_id: newUser.group_id })
    .select({ _id: 1 })
    .exec()
    .then(function(achievementsForGroupArray) {

      _.forEach(achievementsForGroupArray, function(achievementForGroup) {
        newUser.achievements.push(achievementForGroup);
      });
 **newUser.save(function(err, user) {
    // .. generic validation stuff ..
  })**
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      return res.status(400).send(err).end();
    })
```

Comment: Oh right, I am essentially saving before it ends inside the `.then()`?

Comment: right, when you are saving it outside .then() at that time it is not yet initialized because of the asynchronous behavior.

Comment: Cheers fam - Sorted.